# Change the spam flag reason

Tags: feature-request, spam, flag-reasons

Often we see discussions of when spam is spam for the purpose of flagging a question.
Often, when users see vandalism or other inappropriate posts, they feel they have to flag it as spam, which is incorrect according to the current spam flag reason.
I propose to alter the spam flag reason to include other inappropriate stuff, like it is written already for rejecting a suggested edit:

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional **or is otherwise inappropriate**.

Comment: I support your change request. I've seen various reactions on suggested edit from different reviewers. It still remains pretty much vague that  where exactly the line is actually drawn on rejecting a edit.

Comment: No need, it is already in the "offensive" flag: *This question contains content that a reasonable person **would deem inappropriate for respectful discourse**.*

Comment: It's a bit of a grey area.  There's some content that doesn't quite meet the standards for the spam flag, but I find is used by mods to delete it.  Such as utter gibberish.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I think the one you are referring to is headed " it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech". It doesn't have to be that to be inappropriate. A question full of a's and b's is just defacing of the site, and has no use, but it is no spam and not disrespectful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spam is obvious spam (i.e trying to sell me something).  If it isn't spam, then it shouldn't be flagged as spam.

You are basically saying that since users are not using the Spam flag correctly, we should change the definition of the spam to accommodate those users, when in fact, we should be educating those users to flag correctly.

Comment: I understand your point although I still think the current flag reasons are unclear on this matter. Thanks for commenting on this subject.

Comment: @PatrickHofman the unclarity probably comes from how some users define spam.  Some probably think that if it is anything offensive or random, then it must be Spam, whereas SE has a very specific definition.  If I'm not mistaken, the Spam prevention tools rely on proper usage of the flag, so improper usage makes those tools less reliable.  Like I said, we need to educate the users as to what the flag is used for and not expand the definition, and maybe that means linking a definition in the flag dialog or something similar, however given the flag text seems accurate, I doubt it would work.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see the point in this.

The spam flag isn't *supposed* to encompass anything besides promotion. Vandlaism should be reported as `offensive, abusive, or hate speech`. This flag reason includes things that you would "deem inappropriate for respectful discourse", making it usable in this situation. I would say that vandalism can be classified as "abusive".

Comment: The "offensive" and "hate speech" kind of set a different tone for the word "abusive" between them, such that it does not indicate the sort of "abusive" that describes vandalism.

Comment: @Johnathan I see what you're saying, but it's still the most fit flag to use.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's a problem with the flag description itself. (One I'm sure has been raised before...)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find out anything that's **on-topic**, not spam, not offensive, not abusive, not hate speech, not too broad, not primarily opinion based, but nevertheless, **otherwise inappropriate**.

Until there's a convincing example that something like that exists, and happens more often than once a Chinese year, I'd say, current flags and close reasons are fully enough.

Please **don't** add any flag that would suggest they are meant for any moral censorship on the site! There are already guys claiming that questions about meat should be banned, just don't give them anything they may enjoy!