# Providing additional moderation information on main page?

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, moderator-tools

This request I guess is more from a moderator standpoint.  IMO should probably be viewable only by those who can actually do something about it.

[image]

Currently we can see the number of votes, answers and views.  Votes I find very useful any question with a large number of negative votes normally leads me to go and check it even if I couldn't answer it.  Often they need to be closed or flagged

It would be nice to see close votes and possibly flags as well.   If I am scrolling down the list of questions it would be quite helpful in dealing with moderation issues if I could see that someone had flagged an issue with the question.  I think it might be to confusing if issues with answers within a question were also shown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the database servers won't like your request. It will mean a massive load on the question list.

Besides that, functionally I don't it is particularly useful to draw attention to questions from a moderation point of view. There are several queues already there to guide the reviewers in the process of moderation. If you come across a question you will have some information on the close votes, but never on the flags.

Moderators and trusted users have special views to handle flags (diamond only) and close votes. No need to integrate those with the question list.

Comment: Point taken wouldn't want to abuse the database :)  I flagged the request for delete.

Comment: Which request did you flag? This question? Why? @DaImTo

Comment: You are correct its a bad idea If its such a bad idea that it gets -1's its not a useful question and should be removed.   Unfortunately the system wont let me delete it myself.   Actually I didn't realize that having an idea would result I -1's because I didn't take into account the load it would cause to the database.

Comment: That is not correct. Downvotes on a feature request means just disagreement. I give you reasons why I disagree and you immediately want to delete it?

Comment: I have worked on enough systems to understand database load that something like that would cause.  Unless question table already has the information as to the number of flags and closes stored on it you are talking about a lookup for each question.   I have no disagreements with your answer you are correct.

Comment: So then you just delete it?

Comment: Might as well questions with no purpose are a waste of space.  :)

Comment: @DaImTo even if it is a bad idea that doesn't necessarily mean the question is a bad idea. What if someone else comes and asks the same thing tomorrow? Next week? No need to go through the whole discussion again if this already exists.

Comment: and this question has only had a handful of views, others may feel differently :)

Comment: I agree @cai but also like my clean track record.   I am not on meta much so I guess it doesn't matter if I end up with one question with a huge number of -1's for a bad idea.  I leave it to you guys to decide if you want to leave it then.   I don't have the power to delete. it.

Comment: @DaImTo votes on meta (and feature-reqs specifically) aren't necessarily about post quality but about agreement. That's the risk you take posting a feature request.

Comment: You are not the only one with some [negatively received questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231570/245360). Don't worry too much. It is all part of meta.

Comment: My earlier point stands though, this post has had a handful of views and is currently at post score of 0 (+2/-2), not exactly a resounding disagreement :-)